# MsgBox comes up twice using If answer = Yes/No/Cancel

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

I am trying to create a macro that will give me a message box before closing Excel to ask if I want to save changes. When I select No from the message box the message pops up again, then the 2nd time that I chose No it does close.

I don't know very much about VBA programming, I just try to record macro's then edit them slightly. I also search online and copy paste. This is how I put together this code below but obviously something is wrong. (although it works)
I wonder if someone could advise me what needs to be changed in this code. 
Any help appreciated,
Thanks

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim answer As String
    Dim question As String
    Dim OrigName As String


    question = "Do you want to save Changes?"
    answer = MsgBox(question, vbYesNoCancel)

    If answer = vbCancel Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If answer = vbNo Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If

    If answer = vbYes Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\me\Documents\reports\Backup\" + ActiveWorkbook.Name & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh-mm") & ".xlsm")
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

You're already closing the workbook, so there's no need to *Close it again* in your code. Just 'trick' Excel to think changes are saved with `ThisWorkbook.Saved = True` *(Note: This only tells Excel that the changes were saved - **it doesn't actually save them**)* and it won't prompt you to save changes.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Select Case MsgBox("Do you want to save Changes?", vbYesNoCancel)
    Case vbCancel
        Cancel = True
    Case vbNo
        ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
    Case vbYes
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\me\Documents\reports\Backup\" + ActiveWorkbook.Name & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh-mm") & ".xlsm")
    End Select

End Sub
```

And using `ThisWorkbook` in your case would be a better object rather than using `ActiveWorkbook`.